# Difficulty deleting registry keys under HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR

Tags: c#, windows, registry

We are able to create and delete other registry keys using C# but unable to delete subkeys under HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR. We've tried it on Windows 10 Enterprise where we are in the Administrators group as well as a command prompt and regedit in administrator mode. We have also tried it on Windows 10 Home editions but to no avail.

Has anyone else run into this? Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Some registry keys are protected by the system. If you can't delete them in an elevated regedit, I don't see any chance deleting them in C#.

Comment: What permissions are set on the sub keys? Can you change them?

Comment: only *system (S-1-5-18)* have full access to `Properties` subkey. you need enable `SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE` and `SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE` first in token (if you have this) and use `REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE` when open key

Answer (score 0):

I checked the permissions on the keys and the admin group *seems* to have full control but still not able to delete them...

however this tool was shown to me and will ultimately be part of my solution. it allows me to view all usb devices connected and uninstall them and it has command line options so i can setup a scheduled task to run it.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/window-registry